# Generate Python type hints with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, types, swig

The fact that python 3.5+ supports type hints has a great use case when generating wrappers, for instance through SWIG.

Having type hints when working with a large C++ API would make for a much improved experience, since your IDE / linter can perform compile time type checking.

How does one generate type hints with SWIG?

Comment: You could simply inject python code using the `%pythoncode %{ %}` syntax and systematically wrap functions with functions with hints. For classes you could use `%extend`. Preferably, you could include these extentions in your typemaps, so no manual work is needed. Many people are unhappy with python 3.0 so I expect it takes a while before this will be part of the standard typemaps

Answer (score 2):

The swig autodoc feature, can give you this, at least in simple cases.

Adding `%feature("autodoc", "1")` to your SWIG interface code, will generate things like:

```
def function_name(*args, **kwargs):
    """function_name(int x, int y, Foo foo=None, Bar bar=None) -> bool"""
    ...
```

See http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn67